# Diagnosing issues with bloom + github two-factor authentication

Tags: ros, github, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to release a package with bloom, but I also have two-factor authentication on my github account.

I tried following these instructions:
http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/GithubManualAuthorization

and have a `~/.config/bloom` file with my private github token. However, bloom still fails to authenticate:

```
==> git push --dry-run
Username for 'https://github.com': felixduvallet
Password for 'https://felixduvallet@github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/felixduvallet/grasp-synergy-release.git/'
Cannot push to remote release repository.
```

Is there a way to diagnose the bloom+github authentication by itself?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234494/diagnosing-issues-with-bloom-+-github-two-factor-authentication/) by [Felix Duvallet](https://answers.ros.org/users/22253/felix-duvallet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2016-05-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The way I get around this is by adding the following to my .gitconfig:

```
# Always use ssh for github, even if the remote URL uses https or git                                                                                                 
[url "git@github.com:"]                                                                                        
  insteadOf = git://github.com/                                                                                
[url "git@github.com:"]                                                                                        
  insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

Then just make sure that you've added the your ssh key from the computer you are on to your github profile.

---

Originally posted by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) with karma: 606 on 2016-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Duvallet](https://answers.ros.org/users/22253/felix-duvallet/) on 2016-05-18**:
Thanks, I'm adding this information to the wiki.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2016-05-18**:
Awesome, I didn't know that. +1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution I'm personally using is to [create an OAuth token](https://help.github.com/articles/git-automation-with-oauth-tokens/) to use instead of a password, and then use a password manager to store it. The password manager I'm using is [pass](http://passwordstore.org/), along with [pass-git-helper](https://github.com/languitar/pass-git-helper). The advantage over using `~/.config/bloom` is that it doesn't work only for bloom, but for all git commands (just like @jbinney 's solution). Of course if you're not already using pass anyway, @jbinney 's solution is much easier to set up.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2016-05-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Duvallet](https://answers.ros.org/users/22253/felix-duvallet/) on 2016-05-18**:
Sorry, that was a typo on my part. The config file is in fact ~/.config/bloom as per the wiki instructions.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2016-05-18**:
Ok, I've removed that part from my answer.